# Facing error while getting values from URL (javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException:)

Tags: jsf-2

i have a page on which i am using h:link like

```
<h:link outcome="countryPages_View.xhtml">
    <img src="images/afghanistan.png" style="border: none;"/>
    <f:param name="SaarcCountryId" value="11" />
    <f:param name="once" value="true" />
    <f:param name="fromPage" value="homePage" />
</h:link>

<h:link outcome="countryPages_View.xhtml">
    <h:graphicImage  url="images/bangladesh.png" style="margin-left:10px;border: none" />
    <f:param name="SaarcCountryId" value="5" />
    <f:param name="once" value="true" />
    <f:param name="fromPage" value="homePage" />
</h:link>
```

When i click on the image, then url becomes ok. URL becomes like this

```
http://localhost:8080/WIT/faces/countryPages_View.xhtml?SaarcCountryId=1&once=true&fromPage=homePage
```

Then on my page i am getting values like this

```
<ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">SAARC Country View</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="SaarcCountryId" value="#{countryPages_Setup.cntryid}" />
            <f:viewParam name="once" value="#{countryPages_Setup.onse}" />
            <f:viewParam name="fromPage" value="#{countryPages_Setup.page}}" />
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{countryPages_Setup.beforeRenderPage}" />
        </f:metadata>
        <h:form id="countryPages" prependId="false">
            ....
        </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

My bean is like this

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CountryPages_Setup implements Serializable {
    private String cntryid;
    private String page;
    private String onse;

    public void beforeRenderPage(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
        System.out.println(page);
        System.out.println(onse);
        System.out.println(cntryid);        
    } //end of beforeRenderPage()

    //Constructor
    public CountryPages_Setup() {

    } //end of constructor

    // getter and setter
    public String getCntryid() {
        return cntryid;
    }
    public void setCntryid(String cntryid) {
        this.cntryid = cntryid;
    }
    public String getOnse() {
        return onse;
    }
    public void setOnse(String onse) {
        this.onse = onse;
    }
    ...
} //end of class CountryPages_Setup
```

When my page loads i am getting errors.

```
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /countryPages_View.xhtml @20,88 value="#{countryPages_Setup.page}}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

root cause
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /countryPages_View.xhtml @20,88 value="#{countryPages_Setup.page}}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /countryPages_View.xhtml @20,88 value="#{countryPages_Setup.page}}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
```

Why i am getting this error? I made setter and getter for my view params? Also when page loads then first my constructor call. I want to use these f:param values in my constructor. I think after constructor my beforeRenderPage() method will call. How can i get these values in the constructor so i can use it in my constructor?

Thanks

Comment: have you generated getter/setter for your page variable ?

Comment: yes, i didn't post but ofcourse i generated it `public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }` . Getter is also there...

Comment: Tell me one thing. When my page loads and my constructor call then i am doing something like this in the beginning of my constructor `page = ""; -> if (page.equalsIgnoreCase("CountryPages_Detail")) {..} else {...}`. can it be the problem? I mean to say i have set the value when my constructor called and then i am again try to set the values through f:viewparam. Just a guess, may be i am wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a second bracket at the end of the expression: page }}

```
<f:viewParam name="fromPage" value="#{countryPages_Setup.page}}" />
```

Comment: :D:D Thanks buddy it worked ;). But first my constructor call and then the beforeRenderPage(). It means now i have to move my code from constructor to beforeRenderPage(). But i noticed one more thing. My beforeRenderPage() method get call two times. I think because of the JSF life cycle. I am calling database functions based on the result of the querystring. It means my database get hit two times. What should i do? Can you give me any suggestion? Thanks :)